# Setting Up A Raspberry Pi As A Wi-Fi Router

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager

I want to set up a Raspberry Pi 3B as a Wi-Fi router/hostpot. Is there is a quick and easy way to do it without compromising network security? I love the thought of making it into a router because the Raspberry Pi is already a prime candidate for setting up local pages, VPNs, and possibly malware scanners so I can avoid slowing down my tablet with antivirus apps!

What i'm hoping to find is either few simple steps or tools/scripts that will automate the setup process for me.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: I doubt you want a router! A router with 2 ports is pretty useless, and the Pi3 would make a lousy router. If you want a router buy one - it will be cheaper and work better, otherwise ask for what you want to actually do.

Comment: @Milliways Why would a router with 2 ports be pretty useless?

Comment: like @Milliways said - you probably do not really mean a router. ( a gateway / hotspot maybe ? ) Take a look at [PiHole project](https://pi-hole.net/) . It might be what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as an access point - the easy way](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88214/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-an-access-point-the-easy-way) or [Access point as WiFi router/repeater, optional with bridge](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/89803/79866).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of tutorials on the net for transforming the pi into a router / hotspot.

[Example I](https://www.instructables.com/id/Use-Raspberry-Pi-3-As-Router/) [Example II](https://hackernoon.com/raspberry-pi-based-wifi-routers-3b8c7c49143f) [Example III](https://howtoraspberrypi.com/create-a-wi-fi-hotspot-in-less-than-10-minutes-with-pi-raspberry/) and google will produce many more.

But Like I said in comment: As @Milliways suggested - maybe the pi is not the best option for a router as the technical sense of the term. It will be very limited.
If you want something to tinker with as a powerful router take a look maybe at `DDWRT` or `tomato`. [`OpernWRT`](https://openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi) officially supports Pi.

If you want it as a gateway ( for malaware / ads etc ) you might want to look at the [PiHole](http://ttps://pi-hole.net/) project. It can also be extended as a VPN, Network manager, Malaware scanner etc. so it might give you all the functionality you want without acting as a router.

Comment: @user2497 I am not going to go into the merits of `ddwrt` as it is out of scope. But if you want to use the `rpi3` as a router - I provided you with some links already -  you can always try. nothing better than hands-on experience. From my experience - it is limited. but maybe other use-case might be different so I do encourage all to just try and see for yourselves.